# Django AbstractUser with multiple profiles

Tags: django, inheritance, orm, django-users, user-profile

My **models.py** code is given below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="E-mail", unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Profile(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(verbose_name="Phone number", max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class UserProfile(Profile):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="profile")

    group = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Group type",
        choices=GroupChoices.choices(), # Group1, Group2 etc.
        max_length=20
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("user", "group")
```

I'd like to have a possibility to create users with **the same email & phone number**. The only difference would be a membership to different groups.

The code below seems to be working properly, but once there are two users with the same email(which makes user instance unique), it always returns a list of profiles, instead of returning the specific user profile.

One of the concerns is when accessing another model where User model is in a relation by FK. Then it returns a list of profiles, instead of the specific one.

To compare, using Uber app you can be both a passenger & driver (the same email and the same phone number, but different profiles) - I'm trying to achieve something similar.

Is this approach appropriate ? Is it fair enough, for example to create a custom ProfileManager and filter there results ? Or its overcomplicated and it should be done in a different way ?